# Transformation between vector space that removes scalar coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm currently studying up on linear transformations and was wondering if you can define a transformation between two vector spaces like so (a is a scalar constant and x is a vector):

$T(ax) = x$

I'm not sure if this means anything, since $ax$ is itself another vector, so how would you be able to "remove" the $a$ from an arbitrary input vector?

Comment: The problem is ill-posed until you add some restriction to what a "removed scalar coefficient" vector looks like. For example, if you specify that the output is normalized (has norm 1), then the transform $T:x\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ would do the trick.

Comment: T(0) = T(0x) = x  won't be well defined as $x$ can be anything.

Comment: Of course you can define such transformation for a fixed $a \neq 0$ but I don't think this is interesting for you.

Comment: @EugeneShvarts: Notice that the underlying vector space may not have a norm, therefore there may be no unit sphere. You may think of the associated projective space, instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys.  The reason for the wonky question is I was attempting to come up with a counterexample for the simple true/false: "If $T(x + y) = T(x) + T(y)$ then $T$ is linear" which of course is false.  I guess it's enough to just say T must also preserve scalar products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, you may not define such a thing in general and here is why: if $x = a y$, then $T(x) = T(ay) = T(y)$; this shows that the only such $T$ are the ones that may be transported downto the projective space associated to your vector space - in particular, such transformations are *not* linear. If projective spaces are foreign to you, rephrase the above as "the only such transformations are the ones that are constant along $1$-dimensional subspaces (i.e. straight lines)".